# Can not add UIImage items to NSMutableArray - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, nsmutablearray

my application uses .png images from the applications document's folder to show thumbnails at a later time in a pop up. I am trying to add all the .png images from the folder into an array. I know the error is happening when the tempImage object is added to the array, but I am unsure of why this is happening. Does anyone see the issue with this block of code?

```
NSArray *pathforsave = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [pathforsave objectAtIndex:0];


NSArray *getFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                     contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory
                     error:nil];


NSInteger x = 0;


NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"];
NSArray *onlyPNGs = [getFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];

NSMutableArray *Images;
NSUInteger arrayPNGLength = [onlyPNGs count];
for (x=0; x<arrayPNGLength; x++) {
    //first get the path
    NSString *strFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[onlyPNGs objectAtIndex:x]];
    UIImage *tempImage = [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: strFile];
    [Images addObject:tempImage];

}
```

Thanks for your help, I am new to objective c.

Comment: Andrey is right that you need to `alloc`/`init` the `MSMutableArray` before you use it. As an aside, though, the Objective-C [typographic variable naming convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002931-BBCFHEAB) is that variable names (and method names) should start with a lowercase letter. Only class names begin with an uppercase letter. So do `NSMutableArray *images = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
NSMutableArray *Images = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

instead of `NSMutableArray *Images;`

Comment: This works - Thank you. I will accept as answer in 10 minutes when the time limit has ended.